# Chartkick-vue bar chart - "horizontalBar" is not a registered controller

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, chartkick

I want to convert my vertical column chart to a horizontal stacked bar. I use `chartkick-vue` 0.61 with `chart.js` 3.0-beta.

My current code:

```html
<column-chart :data="chartData" suffix="%"
              height="200px"
              :colors="[['#28a745', '#007bff', '#ffc107', '#dc3545']]">
</column-chart>
```

is rendered this way:

[image]

I found this [doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/charts/bar/#stacked-bar-chart), but I have no clue how to pass this to `chartkick-vue`, so I started with horizontal bar:

```html
<bar-chart
  :data="chartData"
  suffix="%"
  height="200px"
  :colors="[['#28a745', '#007bff', '#ffc107', '#dc3545']]"
>
```

but it fails with:

```
Error Loading Chart: "horizontalBar" is not a registered controller
```

This is code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-williamson-upohe

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chart.js`'s [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration/#chart-types) indicate that the `horizontalBar` type was removed in 3.x, but `chartkick-vue` still [uses it](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/blob/c1437a23a7c7a7f7975aee35ca8e7d6f6f89f6a3/vendor/assets/javascripts/chartkick.js#L928).

The solution is to use the current stable release of `chart.js` (2.x) instead of the 3.x beta:

```
npm i -S chart.js@^2
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bar-charts-with-chartkick-vue-chartjs-vz069)

Comment: Ok, I wanted to get away of momentjs bundled in version 2.x but there are side effects :-(

Answer (score 6):

It's actually `type: 'bar'` with `indexAxis: 'y'` in the options now.
See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/horizontal.html